# Ubuntu installer crashes on formatting eMMC drive

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

Unable to install Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS on Asus BR1100CKA laptop. This laptop has an eMMC drive shown as "Generic G1J38E". The Windows 10 NTFS partition was resized and around 29 GB of unallocated space was available for installing Ubuntu. Ubuntu installer crashes during formatting this partition to EXT4.

I have tried Ubuntu Server, Xubuntu, GPARTED Live, etc. multiple times and the installation fails at formatting every single time. I also tried to format the partition as EXT4 from Windows using Disk-Genius and AOMEI-Partition-Assistant. The formatting was successful, but Ubuntu installer keeps crashing.

I really like the laptop, but Windows 10 OS is unacceptable for me. Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1688659/128gb-emmc-drive-on-asus-laptop-unable-to-format-to-ext4

Comment: I have the same problem with my BR1100CKA, and i found one way to make a dual boot on my PC - i bought NVME Pci m2 storage and ubuntu was installed on it. Win 11 and GRUB are on EMMC.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps everyone having this kind of problem with installing Linux on eMMC drive. The root of the problem is lack of hardware drivers in older Linux kernels. The solution comes with the latest Linux kernel. I successfully installed debian-bookworm-DI-alpha2 (Linux Kernel 6.1), released on 2023-02-19, which can be downloaded here: https://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/bookworm_di_alpha2/amd64/iso-cd/ The installation went smooth with no errors and everything works. Ubuntu 22.04, Linux Mint 21.1, Debian 11 and Devuan 4 with Kernel 5.xx all failed to install with fatal error on eMMC drive. Any Linux distro with Kernel 6.1 or newer should also work.